# Update Catalina to Big Sur apache error /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf

Tags: php, macos, apache

I update my macOS from Catalina to Big Sur. After updating my apache is not working. It shows an error

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 556 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: No such file or directory
```

Iam not sure why this error shows me. Please any one suggest me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have faced same problem. I have fixed my problem following three steps

1. First remove file `+php-osx.conf` from `/private/etc/apache2/other/` directory
2. In your `httpd.conf` file just remove **"#"** before **"LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so"**. Using terminal command `sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
3. After completing above two steps you must restart your apache using command `sudo apachectl restart`